# How to create common function for query conditions?

Tags: rust, psql, rust-diesel

I'm using diesel orm to interacte with the database, i have two queries which use similar conditions to fetch the data. Can you suggest a way to create a common function for it?

Schema

```
diesel::table! {
    posts (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        title -> Varchar,
        body -> Text,
        published -> Bool,
    }
}
```

Functions

```
fn count() -> i64 {
  posts.filter(title.eq('mark')).filter(body.eq('good')).count().get_result(&mut con).expect("error")
}
fn list() -> Vec<Posts>{
  posts.filter(title.eq('mark')).filter(body.eq('good')).load::<Posts>(&mut con).expect("error")
}
```

Want to create a function something like

```
fn get_conditions() -> ? {
   posts.filter(title.eq('mark')).filter(body.eq('good'))
}
```

Not able to figure out the return type of the `get_conditions()` function

Tried

```
n get_conditions() -> Filter<posts, _> {
   posts.filter(title.eq('mark')).filter(body.eq('good'))
}
```

gives an error

Comment: What error? Please provide a [mre] including the full error message generated by something like `cargo build`.

Comment: @cafce25 - `error[E0121]: the placeholder \`_\` is not allowed within types on item signatures for return types`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to construct the type based on the functions you call. That requires nesting some types. The first function that you call is [`.filter`](https://docs.diesel.rs/2.0.x/diesel/prelude/trait.QueryDsl.html#method.filter) which returns a [`diesel::dsl::Filter<Self, Pred>`](https://docs.diesel.rs/2.0.x/diesel/helper_types/type.Filter.html), where self corresponds to the type of `posts` (so posts) and `Pred` to whatever you've passed as argument (that's shown in the function signature).
So `Pred` is basically what's returned by [`title.eq("mark")`](https://docs.diesel.rs/2.0.x/diesel/expression_methods/trait.ExpressionMethods.html#method.eq) so [`diesel::dsl::Eq<Self,T>`](https://docs.diesel.rs/2.0.x/diesel/dsl/type.Eq.html) where again `Self` corresponds to `title` and `T` to what you've passed to that function. So `Pred` is `Eq<title, &'static str>`. This gives the type `Filter<posts, Eq<title, &'static str>>`.
I will stop there as the second filter type is basically the same, just with `Self` being the first filter type.

You might want to checkout [this guide](https://diesel.rs/guides/composing-applications.html) which covers the topic with more details.